# How to add libraries with relative path via TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES?

Tags: cmake

In my CMakeLists.txt, I don't know how to give a relative path in `target_link_libraries.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
add_library(FaceDetection SHARED example_wrap.cpp example.cpp  )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../../../Includes/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include)
target_link_libraries(FaceDetection ../../../Includes/OpenCV-3.0.0-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so)
install (TARGETS FaceDetection DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

How can I pass a relative path for target link libraries?

Comment: Looks like XY problem. **Why you need to use relative path** for linked library? Is library intended to be moved after installation? BTW, installing into binary directory (your `install()` command) is bad idea. If you want library to be built in given dir, just set appropriate property: `set_target_properties(FaceDetection PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` or set `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` for apply this rule for all libraries in the project.

Comment: "Tsyvarev" I need to automate cmakelist , every includes files within project folder, using relative path to refer that folder but Include_Directories referred whatever to link

Comment: Hm, I do not understand needing in relative paths. Just use absolute paths, started with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. BTW, `include_directories` automatically transforms relative path to absolute one.

Comment: What's your actual problem? What does not work as you expected is? What's the error message? What's the reason you do not as Tsyvarev advises you?